# How do I earn honor in America's Army?

Tags: americas-army-3

Specifically, respect and personal courage; those are my two lowest stats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the manual for Americas Army](http://manual.americasarmy.com/index.php/Honor_and_Advancement):

> - **Respect** is scoring based on following orders and showing respect for others. Respect points are earned by actions such as completing leader-assigned objectives and securing enemy Soldiers.
> - **Personal Courage** is scoring based on courageous behavior by a Soldier. Players earn Personal Courage points from activities such as neutralizing enemies and completing objectives while badly wounded.

For the sake of completion, I'll list the rest of the categories as well:

> - **Loyalty** is teamwork based scoring. Assisting teammates completing objectives, neutralizing enemies, and other actions earns you points in Loyalty. To earn Loyalty points you must be linked to a teammate when they achieve a scoring opportunity.
> - **Duty** is mission and objective based scoring and is earned when a player wins missions and completes objectives.
> - **Selfless Service** is scoring based on helping others and doing the right thing. Players gain Selfless Service points through such actions as performing medical care on fellow Soldiers, responding to injured and incapacitated Soldiers quickly and performing triage on fellow soldiers in the correct order.
> - **Honor** is the average of all other Army values. When you achieve enough points in your Army Values scores, your Honor level increases. An increase in your Honor level earns a Soldier advancement points and increases the Soldier's rank.
> - **Integrity** is the only Army Value which can cause points to be lost as well as gained. Integrity points are lost by harming fellow Soldiers, damaging military equipment, or harming incapacitated enemy Soldiers.